# Position of element different on desktop vs mobile

Tags: html, css

So I have my media queries set to have an element positioned "X" pixels relative from the previous element at a min-width of 756px (the resolution of my iphone 6S). On my windows desktop, I positioned the element to where I want it to be. However, when I open the site up on my iphone (using the default Safari browser), the element is off by over a hundred pixels! The element is positioned higher on my iphone than it shows on my desktop. Any ideas? I checked my zooms on my desktop browser and they are all set to 100%.

edit: Here is a fiddle mockup of my code. https://jsfiddle.net/8f6y1pdx/1/

```
<header>
    <div id = "navContainer"><h1>Hello</h1></div>
    <div id = "backgroundImage"><img src = "http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/4/18/laMvrx.jpg" width = "2560" alt = "bg image"></div>
</header>

<body>
    <div id = "contentOneContainer">Container one</div>
    <div id = "contentTwoContainer">Container two</div>
</body>
```

and the css

```
html, body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#navContainer{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

#backgroundImage{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -2;
}

#backgroundImage img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 2560px;
}

#contentOneContainer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    top: 417px;
    z-index: 0;
    color: white;
}

#contentTwoContainer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: gray;
    position: relative;
    top: 417px;
    z-index: 0;
    color: white;
}

/*----------------------------------*\
  Responsive
\*----------------------------------*/
@media (min-width: 757px){
    #contentOneContainer{
    background-color: red;
    }
}
```

If you adjust the screen size, at 757px I have the background color of the container switch. Basically, on my desktop, I am lining up the bottom of the image with the top of the first container. When viewed on my iphone 6s (I don't know how to make this work when viewing the fiddle on mobile) the bottom of the image and the top of the container are a hundred plus pixels apart. I hope this helps a little. Also, sorry if my code blows.

Comment: Fiddle your code. It will easy to help you.

Comment: Go And Search On Google

Comment: Added a fiddle plus code.

Answer (score 1):

Add  viewport meta tag in the head section for the media queries to work on mobile.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile

Comment: While the link may answer the question, it's always best to put the key parts of the link in your answer directly. This serves two purposes: people are saved the trouble of visiting an external link and even if the link is broken, people can still find the information in your answer.

Comment: Tried adding <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

Comment: Pressed enter too early! Anyways, I added that and it throws everything off. Why is that? It now displays as if not at a 756px width :/

Comment: Mobile browsers by default opens the web page in zoomed out view.
For the media queries to work properly we would want to disable the zoom.
Meta viewport that you added disables the zoom on mobile browsers.